# charAt() cannot find symbol

Tags: java, string-length, charat, cannot-find-symbol

I'm trying to use an if statement that looks like this. If a method has received an argument into its parameter `line` of type `String`, then why do I get a `cannot find symbol` error when using a `line.charAt(x)` call? Here's the code fragment.

```
for(int x = 0; x < line.length; x++) {
    if(line.charAt(x) != ' ') {
        //rest of code
    }
}
```

What's more, the `length` call also has a `cannot find symbol` error.

Can anyone see a solution to this without importing anything in the class? Thanks.

Comment: Is this Java, C#, or something else? What is the declaration and value of `line`? What is "rest of code"? I ask because perhaps you can use a "for each" loop instead. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: if this is java you should write `line.length()` if it's javascript you should write `var x = 0;` If it's any other language I don't know the behavior

Comment: Ah. I was confused because with arrays you write the call without parentheses, but it appears with a `String` object you do use `line.length()`. Thanks! Do you want to post that as an answer so I can mark it as correct?

Comment: Tip: use an IDE, it will helpfully suggest or auto-complete methods for you.

Comment: is that code inside a method? if not, that's your problem.

Comment: @OCDkirby At arrays, length is not a method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java, to find the length of a `String` we need to use [`String.length()`](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-length)

```
for(int x = 0; x < line.length(); x++) {
    if(line.charAt(x) != ' ') {
        //code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `line.length` while you should be using `line.length()` in Java. See more about `String.length()` and other String utils over [here](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#length(java.lang.String)).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   String line = "JAva java java";
    for(int x = 0; x < line.length(); x++) {
        if(line.charAt(x) != ' ') {
            System.out.println("text-->"+line.charAt(x));
        }
    }
```